# TPM Provisioning not working with actual TPM device

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, dragonboard

On the DragonBoard 410c, I can provision the TPM via the Device Portal or with the IoT Core Dashboard, and in both cases, the stored information is not available via the `TpmDevice(0)` logical device.

`TpmDevice(0).GetDeviceID()` does return a value, but it is not the configured value, and `.GetHostName()` and `.GetSasToken()` both return `null`.

I can't test on the MinnowBoard Max, because the TPM 2.0 implementation on that board is not complete, and the Raspberry Pi doesn't have a TPM.

I have not tried using the software simulated TPM on the MBM because I want this to actually be secure.

Here's my code, for what it's worth.

```
TpmDevice myDevice = new TpmDevice(0);
string hubUri = myDevice.GetHostName();   // returns null
string deviceId = myDevice.GetDeviceId(); // returns wrong value
string sasToken = myDevice.GetSASToken(); // returns null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following tutorial to verify you have the right TPM version enabled and fTPM is functioning:

[Setup firmware TPM (fTPM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/secure-your-device/setuptpm#setup-firmware-tpm-ftpm)

Comment: This wasn't a question about the MBM fTPM so much as it was about Azure credential storage.  That said, here's what the MBM shows in its TPM page after setting it up.  https://i.imgur.com/Oe7eUAW.png  Note the "Not supported" text.

Comment: Looks like the MBM TPM doesn't support the features which are required to store Azure credentials.  The DragonBoard does; why doesn't credential storage work there?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the Insider Preview for the Dragonboard.  The current release (15063) does not have this issue.

<del>Marking myself the answer.</del>

Problem apparently made it all the way through the insider builds into production. 
 16299 shows the same behavior for me as its insider preview versions did.

https://github.com/ms-iot/security/issues/29

Comment: This is no longer the solution, if your IoT Core device is up to date.  The bug from the Insider Preview versions seems to have made it through to production...